# Resetting the values of the dynamically generated table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I am working on a web form wherein I am retrieving data from database using ajax call and displaying it in a dynamic table each row in a table has a checkbox which is checked and unchecked based on some value in the database. Next I want to clear only values of the table and then when I click on another ajax call button the values should get populate in the previously generated table with all the checkbox unchecked. How do I achieve this or is there any other way to achieve this. Even a small lead on this would be helpful.

Comment: Providing an example of the dynamically generated `html` code would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check if a cell has a checkbox and uncheck or clear the content accordingly,  like this:

```js
$('#clrBtn').click(function(){
  //Itterate every cell
  $('#myTable td').each(function( index ) {
    //Check if cell contains checkbox
    if($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').length<1)  $(this).empty(); //Clear
    else $(this).find('input').prop('checked', false); // Uncheck
  });
});
```

```css
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#myTable td{
  border:  2px black solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Test1</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test2</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="clear" id='clrBtn'/>
```

Comment: Ok. it helped. Next if i want to display new data in that empty table, how would i achieve it? @TheodoreK.

Comment: @Praveen Raikar, I want to help you with that but it's not possible without knowing your data structure and your table structure. Can you update your question?